# Unable to identify jbutton object in jtree using Testcomplete tool

Tags: java, javascript, swing, jtree, testcomplete

We are working on a java swing application and trying to automate testing using TestComplete tool. We are able to identify jTree object but unable to identify the jbutton object which resides inside the jtree. Can there be anyway we can identify this?

TestComplete identifies the object tree like this:

> {Sys.Process("javaw").SwingObject("Application").SwingObject("JRootPane",
>   "",
>   0).SwingObject("null.layeredPane").SwingObject("null.contentPane").SwingObject("ApplicationBusyLayer").SwingObject("FrameContainer").SwingObject("DmsContentPane").SwingObject("JLayeredPane",
>   "",
>   0).SwingObject("ApplicationCardPanel").SwingObject("ApplicationPanelContainer").SwingObject("ApplicationBusyLayer").SwingObject("DetailView",
>   "", 0).SwingObject("InventoryUpdateDetailPanel", "",
>   0).SwingObject("JTabbedPane", "Designer", 0).SwingObject("JPanel", "",
>   0).SwingObject("JSplitPane", "", 0).SwingObject("JSplitPane", "",
>   0).SwingObject("JSplitPane", "", 0).SwingObject("JPanel", "",
>   0).SwingObject("FilterPanel", "", 0).SwingObject("JXLayer", "",
>   0).SwingObject("JScrollPane", "", 0).SwingObject("JViewport", "",
>   0).SwingObject("FilterTree", "", 0)}

Comment: Can you post here your Java code that puts a button into a tree? It is hard to understand what you application looks like without this.

Answer (score 0):

Launch your application from test complete and then spy the control, hope this will help you, Else go to the possible parent node and get child, check what are those and use it.....